# HTML5 Javascript Object Has Been Clicked On

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a game where your mouse is a cross hair and you click on zombies moving across the screen. I'm having troubles figuring out how to find if the mouse has clicked on a zombie. The zombies are made in JavaScript so I can't use the onclick attribute in HTML. This is my code.

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

$(document).ready(function(){
var canvasWidth = 640;
var canvasHeight = 480;

var canvas = $("#gameCanvas")[0];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var score = 0;
var timer = 0;
var spawnZombie = false;

//crosshair
var crossHair = new Image();
var crosshairX = 50;
var crosshairY = 50;
crossHair.src = "media/crosshair.png";

//zombies
var zombies = [];
var zombieLeft = new Image();
zombieLeft.src = "media/zombieLEFT.gif";
var zombieRight = new Image();
zombieRight.src = "media/zombieRIGHT.gif";

var fps = 30;
setInterval(function(){
    update();
    draw();
}, 1000/fps);

function update(){
    timer += 1;

    crosshairX = mouseX - 445;
    crosshairY = mouseY - 125;

    if(timer >= 70){
        timer = 0;
        spawnZombie = true;
    }

    zombies.forEach(function(zombie) {
        zombie.update();
        document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
            console.log(zombie.x.toString() + ", " + zombie.y.toString());
            //if(mouseX)
        };
    });

    zombies = zombies.filter(function(zombie){
        return zombie.active;
    });

    if(spawnZombie){
        zombies.push(Zombie(null, "left"));
        zombies.push(Zombie(null, "right"));
        spawnZombie = false;
    }
}
function draw(){
    context.clearRect(0,0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.font = "20px Comic Sans MS";
    context.fillText("Score: " + score, 50, 50);

    zombies.forEach(function(zombie) {
        zombie.draw();
    });

    context.drawImage(crossHair, crosshairX, crosshairY, 100, 100);
}

function Zombie(I, dir){
    I = I || {};
    I.active = true;

    I.speed = 5;

    I.y = getRandomInt(50, 350);
    if(dir == "left"){
        I.x = 800;
    }
    else if(dir == "right"){
        I.x = -100;
    }
    I.width = 100;
    I.height = 100;

    I.inBounds = function() {
        return I.x >= 0 && I.x <= canvasWidth &&
        I.y >= 0 && I.y <= canvasHeight;
    };

    I.draw = function(){
        if(dir == "left"){
            context.drawImage(zombieLeft, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
        else if(dir == "right"){
            context.drawImage(zombieRight, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    };

    I.update = function(){
        if(dir == "left"){
            this.x -= this.speed;
        }
        else if(dir == "right"){
            this.x += this.speed;
        }
    };

    I.onclick = function(){
        I.remove();
    };
    return I;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
});
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
    mouseX = event.pageX;
    mouseY = event.pageY;
});
```

This is the specific spot where I'm trying to detect if the zombie has been clicked on within my update functio

```
zombies.forEach(function(zombie) {
            zombie.update();
            document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
                console.log(zombie.x.toString() + ", " + zombie.y.toString());
                //if(mouseX)
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use the `onclick` attribute in HTML.

But you *can* use the `addEventListener` method in your javascript:

**eg.**

```
zombieLeft.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I tried adding the event listener in the update method and also tried after in the I.draw method in the zombie methods.

Comment: It's definitely working. Something else won't be working. You can deploy `console.log` messages throughout your code to find out what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.onmousedown = function(event) { 
            console.log(zombie.x.toString() + ", " + zombie.y.toString());
            if(event.pageX == zombie.x && event.pageY == zombie.y){
             //Zombie clicked
            }
        };
```

This is pseudo code. You can attach event and you can check for x and y.